# Efficient way to compute coincidence of space and time

Tags: matlab, polyline

Given a 3-dimensional polyline `P = {(x1, y1, t1), ..., (xn, yn, tn)}` and another polyline `Q = {(x1, y1, t1), ..., (xm, ym, tm)}` (m not necessarly equal to n, so polylines could have different length), coincidence in space and time occurs when the trajectories of moving objects P and Q, have some timing and positioning in common (Point A, as seen in example figure is a coincidence point cause `(xa, ya, ta)==(xb, yb, tb)` obviously coincidence point could be a point outside of initial sets of point)
[image: coincidence in space and time]
The concept is quite simple and visual perspective easily identify where colocation happen. Hardest part is how to realize an algorithm that efficiently compute coincidence and return the calculated (remember: point could be outside given sets of points) x, y coords and time t of where colocation happens!! This algorithm will be developed in Matlab so I have all necessary to rapidly work.

Best regards

Comment: Do you need to deal with interpolation?

Comment: No, I don't. PS: I have these sets of points, that define two polylines, but coincidence point could be a point outside the initial sets of points.

Comment: If the coincidence not might not be in the original set of points, then yes, you are effectively having to deal with interpolating between points.  But this now becomes a very difficult problem; possibly ill-defined.  You first need to define an interpolation method, and you then need to define a threshold for "how close do things need to be before they're considered coincident?".

Comment: Someone know an already developed script to do this? I have found http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837 this for 2-dimensional curve and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that x, y, z are functions of t for all segments of each polyline, here's a brute-force start.  in 4 dimensions: P has segments `p1 from (x_start(t), y_start(t), z_start(t), t) to (x_end(t), y_end(t), z_end(t), t)`, and similarly Q

```
for each segment p of P
    for each segment q of Q
        if p intersects q (in 4 dimensions)
            output intersection point
```

the intersection condition is:
  there exists `alpha` and `beta` in `[0,1]` where `alpha * px_start(t) + (1 - alpha) * (px_end(t) - px_start(t)) = beta * qx_start(t) + (1 - beta) * (qx_end(t) - qx_start(t))` and 2 more similar conditions for y and z

solvability of the intersection condition depends on what are the functions x(t), y(t), z(t) -- linear? polynomials? etc.

Comment: `alpha` and `beta` would need to have the same values for each of the three x, y, z conditions

Comment: What if I first compute the colocation in space, using http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837 and only  subsequently I control if time match around a defined threshold? This is quite rude and can't be consider a best practice, but after all, execution time probably will be not so worst.

Comment: I think this will cause you more troubles. You then would need to find which line segments would belong to the found points - and then still go back to solving the intersections in 3 dimensions.

Comment: if you mean you would generate the curves at various intervals of time and see if they intersect?  the execution time would depend on how small the time intervals are, and the possibility of "missing" an intersection would be higher the bigger the time interval.  so depending on what the expected behavior of the curves is, the approach you suggest (the matlab intersections function linked above) might be reasonable.

Comment: No I mean, check with "Intersactions" function if the two polylines intersect and in what point, then I will check in that point if curves express the same time around a proper threshold.